# How to have browser open a file from a custom protocol?

Tags: c#, javascript, firefox, browser, protocols

I currently have a url that looks like this: protocol://folder/file.js

I can open this same file from my local disk using a url like file://C:\folder\file.js

When the application is run inside its own provided environment, this protocol is available and it loads the file just fine from my local disk.

I'd like to also be able to access these files for times when I run this application inside a regular browser like firefox or chrome.

I've managed to register this protocol on my windows machine and forward the url to a custom c# program that can then open the proper file in browser again. However, it opens the file in a new tab and doesn't seem to work properly when attempting to open the file from a  tag on the page.

Is there an easy way to get firefox (or any other browser) to open a file from a custom protocol directly in the tab that requested it?

Comment: Interesting question - I've heard of such things in phone environments, but never for ordinary desktops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in FireFox, you must implement a [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM) object. There are [instructions on how to do this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FirefoxProtocol.aspx) in C++. For C#, you follow the same instructions, but use [GeckoFX](http://www.geckofx.org/) to get wrappers for .NET.

Comment: And once this is done, it's true that in order for it to work the Firefox end user has to install something, right?

Comment: @Pointy - Yes. Its basically a plugin that the user must install.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was looking for.